# Firebase & iOS 14 > Will dynamic links tracking and campaigns continue to work?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

As most of you are probably aware, **iOS 14 will basically put an end to app acquisition tracking** as we know it.

Here are two great articles that explore the issue in length:

- [The App Attribution Industry Is Dead](https://blog.branch.io/the-app-attribution-industry-is-dead-embrace-the-post-idfa-era-with-branch/)
- [How To Prepare Your Mobile App and Attribution Stack for Apple’s iOS 14 Privacy and IDFA Changes](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-prepare-your-mobile-app-and-attribution-stack-for-apples-ios-14-privacy-and-idfa-changes/)

Putting aside the critical changes most people will have to make to their business models, my question has to do with Firebase's dynamic links in particular.

Since they basically rely on copying a link in the pasteboard, I already know they might now trigger a warning banner — [although the Firebase team has apparently been proactive with this matter](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5893).

What I don't know at this point is whether they will continue to work or not when users disallow ad tracking.

My team and I have tried building one of our React Native apps with XCode 12 beta on a simulator running iOS 14, but haven't been able to retrieve any value from the dynamic links — whereas it currently works with iOS 13. There might be other factors at play though, so it's difficult to draw our own conclusions at this point.

My questions provided that the users have opted out of tracking:

1. Will we still be able to read the dynamic link url in-app?
2. Will Google Analytics still receive the UTM parameters and get campaigns' results?
3. If the answer is no to any of these questions, what are the workarounds or third-party solutions you've found?

Your insights will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: branch io team is already working on it. We have to wait n watch.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's blog post: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/supporting-ios-14

If IDFA is not accessible:

- No impact for link-opening functionality
- When used with Google Analytics, attribution for link conversion events is unavailable.